# Spring Boot Compare String in @Value using SpEL

Tags: spring-boot, spring-el

I want to evaluate if a spring profile is local using `SpEL`

I tried the following but can't get it correctly

```
@Value("#{spring.profiles.active == 'local'}") 
private boolean isLocal;
//Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'spring' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public or not valid?

@Value("#{${spring.profiles.active} == 'local'}") 
private boolean isLocal;
//Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'local' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public or not valid?
```

I also tried the following, but no luck:

```
@Value("#{spring.profiles.active.equals('local')}") 
private boolean isLocal; 

@Value("#{spring.profiles.active eq 'local'}") 
private boolean isLocal;
```

Is it not possible to do something like this? Or i did it wrongly?

Comment: As an alternative you can autowire the Spring Environment and use that: `public boolean isLocal{ return environment.acceptsProfiles("local");}`. I would normally encapsulate any profile specific behaviour however and use the `@Profile` annotation to have the correct implementation injected at runtime.

Comment: In SPEL can you try: `@Value("#{environment.acceptsProfile('local')}")`

Answer (score 18):

You need to quote the result of the property placeholder resolution:

```
@Value("#{'${spring.profiles.active}' == 'local'}")
```

Otherwise, SpEL tries to parse it; hence

> Property or field 'local' cannot be found

Comment: This is working well, the answer should be accepted. thanks