# Spring spel expression not working, for boolean value

Tags: java, spring

I have my application config have a property like

```
 @Value("#{new Boolean(environment['spring.profiles.active']!='dev')}")
private boolean is24;
```

Now in two runtime env application-prod where VM variable is set like

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=prod
```

and an env application-dev where VM variable is like

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=dev
```

but the value of is24 is always coming as true. Any idea how can I fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Boot Compare String in @Value using SpEL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57321758/spring-boot-compare-string-in-value-using-spel)

Answer (score 0):

While I posted a comment how to achieve a goal you might have, this doesn't answer your question, and so here is the answer:

Your Spring Expression is (if working correctly) checking the content of the environment variable *spring.profiles.active*, while you are setting the active spring profile with a Java system property. Those two do not automatically reflect each other.

You can set the Spring profile both via environment variable and System property, but this is not a general behaviour of environment variables and System properties.

Comment: Both Comments and Answers don't help me. I am following a guide on where they are doing it.